# Tensorflow Implementation of image gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision

### Issue

I am trying to implement image gradients from scratch. I understand that there are multiple ways to do it (including Sobel and other filters). My question is regarding the Tensorflow implementation of image gradient.

TF implements image gradients by this method as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L3798-L3869). So according to the TF documentation, for a dummy input,

```py
  [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
  [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
  [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
  [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
  [20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]
```

dy and dx are respectively,

```py
dy = [[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

dx = [[1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]],
```

**But when using Sobel filter** (as shown [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-images/1407/5)) my outputs are,

```py
dx = [[[[-8., -8., -8.],
          [-8., -8., -8.],
          [-8., -8., -8.]]]]

dy = [[[[-40., -40., -40.],
          [-40., -40., -40.],
          [-40., -40., -40.]]]]
```

While I understand both are accepted ways of calculating the gradient, my question is,

1. Why aren't the results from these two methods equal?
2. Is there are way to convert the results of one method into the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why aren't the results from these two methods equal?

Because they do different things. Tensorflow's `image_gradients` function computes the finite difference approximation to the derivatives, which is equivalent to convolving with the two kernels:

```
 |  1 -1 |                     |  1 |
                               | -1 |
```

The Sobel filter convolves with these two kernels:

```
|  1  0 -1 |                |  1  2  1 |
|  2  0 -2 | / 8            |  0  0  0 | / 8
|  1  0 -1 |                | -1 -2 -1 |
```

These are two different ways to estimate the gradient.

Note that some implementations use a different normalization. The result for Sobel in the OP is exactly 8 times as large as the expected value of the derivatives, so it is not normalizing the kernels at all. It is missing the `/8` needed to get the right magnitude.

> Is there are way to convert the results of one method into the other?

Yes, I guess you could figure out how to do this, but why would you want to? It is much easier to directly compute the desired output from the input image.